# Firebird SQL test if string contains DATE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

Is there any way to test if a string contains a DATE like 31.12.2018 ?

Like

```
SELECT date_string FROM table where date_string LIKE '%.*.*%'
```

Or something like that?

Comment: make a stored procedure parsing the dates of those several formats that you do support, and then use it in the query

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto) comparison predicate, which uses SQL regular expressions. However depending on the size of the text, this might not be very efficient.

The following predicate will work:

```
date_string similar to '%[[:DIGIT:]]{2}.[[:DIGIT:]]{2}.[[:DIGIT:]]{4}%'
```

See the language reference on [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto) for details on the syntax.

You may want to rethink your design and use explicit columns with an actual SQL `DATE` if you need to apply query logic on them, instead of relying on parsing things within text columns.

Comment: How can I now test if a field contains the current date if the field also can contain normal text? CAST(Current_Timestamp AS DATE)=  CAST(SubString(field FROM 1 FOR 2 ) || '.' || SubString(field FROM 4 FOR 2 ) || '.' || SubString(field FROM 7 FOR 4 ) AS DATE)

Comment: @MichaelMüller That doesn't work, you either need to use [`CONTAINING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-predicates.html#fblangref25-commons-predcontaining) with the preformatted date, or as I said: You may want to rethink your design and use explicit columns with an actual SQL DATE if you need to apply query logic on them, instead of relying on parsing things within text columns. BTW: Your use of `CAST(Current_Timestamp AS DATE)` doesn't make much sense: just use `CURRENT_DATE` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I Will try CONTAINING. I find it pretty difficult to find the right information in the Firebird doc. I cant change the DB field, its a ERP DB i just read from.